# JQuery Dialog's CSS content will remain when changing pages

Tags: jquery, html, dialog, background-image, jquery-ui-dialog

The index.html page where the button of my JQuery dialog has a background image attached to the page using CSS. The dialog.html page that is linked has a different background image than the index.html page.

When you press the button to open the dialog page, the page changes to dialog.html in the web browser. However, the Developer tool's inspector still believes it is using the CSS from the index.html page.

I link to the dialog.html page from the index.html by doing this:

```
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content" data-theme="b">
        <a href="dialog.html" class="ui-btn ui-btn-b ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-icon-check ui-btn-icon-left" data-transition="pop">Sign Up Now!</a></p>
    </div>
```

This is how the dialog.html handles the information that comes in:

```
    <div data-role="page" data-dialog="true" data-theme="b">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h4>Join Our Team</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-content" role="main">
            <form method="post" action="email.php">
                <div>
                    <label class="ui-hidden-accessible">Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" value="">
                    <label class="ui-hidden-accessible">Age:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="age" placeholder="Age" value="">
                    <label class="ui-hidden-accessible">Email:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Google Play Email" value="">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
                </div>
            </form>             
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here is the CSS that is associated with the code:

```
    body.home {
        background: url(img/WebsiteBackground.jpg);
        background-position:20% 50%;
        background-attachment:fixed;
        background-size:cover;
    }
    .ui-page {
        background: transparent;
    }
    .ui-content{
        background: transparent;
    }
    body.dialog {
        background: url(img/white.jpg);
        background-position:20% 50%;
        background-attachment:fixed;
        background-size:cover;
    }
    .ui-header .ui-title {
        color:black;
        margin-right: 10%;
        margin-left: 10%;
    }
```

Comment: Comment: you can also set up a fiddle (search for JS fiddle) to get an answer more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place an ajax-data="false" at the end of each of your links to stop the JQuery Mobile from running.

```
    <a href="your_page.html" class="your_class" ajax-data="false">Sign Up Now!</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the class in your body tags in respective pages as follows

In index page

```
<body class="home">
```

In dialog page

```
<body class="dialog">
```

Comment: Those are already implemented in there. if I was to say refresh the dialog.html page, then the css will kick in for body.dialog